# Screen jumps after hiding keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard

I'm ***not*** asking how to prevent keyboard from pushing up the screen when it pops up.

When I click an `EditText` the keyboard shows up, and the screen remains unchanged. But the problem is when I click outside the `EditText`, the keyboard hides ***and then*** (after about half a second) the screen jumps a little (leaving a white background at the bottom) and then settles back down.

I'm using a custom Keyboard and a custom EditText.

In the activity I've set:

`getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);`

And when the `EditText` gains focus this is how I show up the keyboard:

```
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)MainApplication.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputMethodManager.showSoftInput( view, 0 );
```

And hide it when `EditText` loses focus:

```
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)MainApplication.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

**EDIT:**

Note that when I press **DONE** on the keyboard, the keyboard just hides (without the screen jumping) but the EditText doesn't lose focus. So if it's possible to just simulate a **DONE** press when the `EditText` is about to lose focus, this would be fine with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved it:

I set an `OnTouchListener` on the main layout (it's a `LinearLayout`) and hided the keyboard there:

```
mainLinearLayout.setOnTouchListener( new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch( View v, MotionEvent event ) {
      InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)MainApplication.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
      inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
      return false; //*SEE NOTE BELOW
    }
} );
```

***NOTE**:

It turns out that if I return `true` (the event is consumed), the keyboard hides, but the `EditText` doesn't lose focus. And if I return `false` (the event is not yet consumed), the keyboard hides, and the `EditText` loses focus (either way, no screen jumping)